# Beginner-friendly IDE for SaSS

Tags: windows-7, web-development

Getting to grips with [SaSS](http://sass-lang.com/) and the command line, although I like the feel of it. It isn't the same as terminal and since I use Windows at work I just try and avoid it, so I searched around for a software to help and came across [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) and [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/). Which of these is more beginner friendly, or are there other software that are easier to use?

Comment: The part "Which of these is more beginner friendly" is up to you, this is not a "what's your opinion site". Please do your homework first. I suggest you investigate Koala and Scout and if they don't satisfy your needs, [update your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/13341/edit) with the reason why they don't match your requirements. While looking at them you'll automatically come up with the requirements that count for you, and that you can (should) add to your question to improve it. As your question is now, it's tempting to interpret it as "Can you do my work for me?"

Comment: @JanDoggen you misunderstand the question entirely then, beginner friendly isn't a opinion-based thing, it's down to a UI that actually helps and evolvs the user's understanding of using a UI